# Generic class for functions with any signature c#

Tags: c#, python, .net, oop

I am trying to convert python code to c#

```
  class fwrapper:
      def __init_ _(self,function,childcount,name):
          self.function=function
          self.childcount=childcount
          self.name=name
  class node:
      def __init_ _(self,fw,children):
          self.function=fw.function
          self.name=fw.name
           self.children=children
      def evaluate(self,inp):
          results=[n.evaluate(inp) for n in self.children]
          return self.function(results)
```

I am finding it difficult to achieve in c# . 
1. In class fwrapper.function it can take function with any signature . 
2. To obtain the return type of the function which can be used to mention return type of the evaluate function

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if you had something like this:

```
public class FWrapper<TChild, TResult>{

    private int childCount;
    private string name;
    private Func<TChild, TResult> function;

    public Func<TChild, TResult> Function { get { return function; } }

    public FWrapper(Func<TChild, TResult> Function, int ChildCount, string Name){
        this.childCount = ChildCount;
        this.name = Name;
        this.function = Function;
   }
}

public class Node<TChild, TResult>{

    private FWrapper<TChild, TResult> fw;
    private IEnumerable<TChild> children;

    public Node(FWrapper<TChild, TResult> FW, IEnumerable<TChild> Children){
        this.fw = FW;
        this.children = Children;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TResult> Evaluate(){

        var results = new List<TResult>();

        foreach(var c in children){
            results.Add(fw.Function(c));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

You now have a FWrapper class that takes in any function that takes TChild as a parameter and returns a TResult and a Node class that works with the same TChild and TResult types, so, for example you could do this (trivial example)

```
//Generic function that takes an int and returns a string
var func = new Func<int, string>(childInt => {
    var str = "'" + childInt.ToString() + "'";
    return str;
});

var fw = new FWrapper<int, string>(func, 10, "Foobar");
var children = new List<int>(){ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

var node = new Node<int, string>(fw, children);
var results = node.Evaluate();

foreach(var r in results){
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}

//'1'
//'2'
//..
//..
//'9'
//'10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing something like this?

```
class Node {
    private FWrapper fw;
    private List<Node> children;

    public Node(FWrapper fw, List<Node> children){
        this.fw = fw;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public Evaluate(Object inp){
        var results = from child in children select child.Evaluate(inp);
        return fw.function(results);
    }

}
```

Its just a starting point.